# LED indicator controlled by MOSFET

Tags: led, diodes, nmos

I was just looking at a reference design and I can't see how this simple circuit makes any sense:

It uses an [EVERLIGHT](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ppotq6gck56k56/19-21-G6C-AM2P1-3T.pdf?dl=0) LED and an  [NTZD3154N](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8zx2coyxewrpg8d/NTZD3154N-D.pdf?dl=0) dual-transistor:

[image]

I couldn't find the operation point of the circuit.

Given that VGS = 1.8V, the VDS should be small enough not to burn the LED.

For VGS = 1.8, I see that for small VDS's, the current exceeds 1A which is a lot.

How can this make sense? The graph of the diode shows forward voltage in the range of [0mA - 50mA], and on the other side we have a transistor that passes a lot of current with such huge VGS.

What am I missing here?

Update:
Considering the answers I got, 20mA of current means the resistor has VR = 2V, the Anode gets 1.3V, and assuming VF=2V it means the cathode will be -0.7? how does it make sense that the cathode which is the VDS of the transistor is negative? did the source and drain here switch sides?

Comment: Graph shows capabilities without a circuit.  Factor in LED behavior and impact of resistor into your calculations.

Comment: why people are voting to close this question? it's a legitimate question and I gave all the details!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rds(on) with 1.8V drive is typically 0.7 ohm. So you have an LED with 100.7 ohms in series when the MOSFET is on.

[image]

Whether it's 0.7 or 0.9 or 0.5\$\Omega\$ the LED current and brightness will not vary significantly. So the MOSFET does the switching and the resistor controls the current.

To determine the current, draw the load-line of the 100 ohm resistor and 3.3V supply on the nonlinear LED curve and look for the intersection:

The load line goes from 3.3V with zero current to 3.3V/100\$\Omega\$ = 33mA with zero LED voltage.

Comment: 20mA of current means the resistor has VR = 2V, the Anode gets 1.3V, and assuming VF=2V it means the cathode will be negative? does it make sense that VDS = -0.7V? and what about the 350mA that was shown in the table for VGS = 1.8 and 0.7 < RDS_ON < 0.9? it contradicts with the 20mA.

Comment: @Xhero39 Yes, there is an issue with the load line because the x axis does not start at 0V. I’ll remove it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The point is to turn the transistor on like it was a switch.

The LED current will be handled by the resistor.

Answer (score 2):

In the datasheet, the LED is characterized at 20 mA.  At this current, the chart shows the typical forward voltage as 2.0 V.

Working with that, assume the FET is perfect, and its fully enhanced channel resistance, Rdson, is 0 ohms.  The circuit is now a 3.3 V source, a 100 ohm resistor, an LED with 2.0 V across it, and GND.  That calculates out to a circuit current of just 13 mA.  The actual value for Rdson will reduce this somewhat.